# Is there a way to dynamically use a store value in a hook?

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I have a `handle` hook that redirects whenever a particular store's value is false :

```js
export const handle = async({event, resolve}) => {
  if (get(store))
    return resolve(event)
  return new Response('Redirect', {status: 303, headers: {Location: '/'}})
}
```

The problem is that in a production environment, the `hooks.js` file is served from `build/server/_app/immutable/chunks`, which in short loads the file in an immutable way, thus rendering the `get` call ineffective (it never gets reevaluated after the first time).

This obviously does not occur in a dev server, as <s>nothing is server-side rendered</s> only the first page load is server-side rendered.

Is there something to fix, or is there a more idiomatic way of achieving this (code that's run on any page while depending on a reactive value) ?

Comment: (The dev server also server-side renders on the first page load.)

Answer (score 0):

There absolutely is. [As per the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks), the `handle` function takes two arguments: `event` and `resolve`. You can add custom data to the request by populating the `event.locals` object.

For example:

```
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Handle} */
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  event.locals.user = await getUserInformation(event.request.headers.get('cookie'));
 
  const response = await resolve(event);
  response.headers.set('x-custom-header', 'potato');
 
  return response;
}
```